Has anyone cursed anyone to go to naraka?
Has anyone in history of Sanatana Dharma cursed to go to naraka?

Yes Nachiketa is agood example.

Nachiketa wasnt cursed..he just obeyed his father when his father said "I have given you to Yama"
